# Android binding library conflicts

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

**Problem :**
I have two Android binding libraries in my solution(C#) and each one of them has specific set of .jar files referring, and these .jar files are from 3rd party. When any one of the binding library is added to the solution then all the classes and interface defined in the .jar files are detected during compile time and everything works perfectly fine but if I add both binding libraries to the solution then there is a conflict between some of the .jar files in both of the binding libraries. Classes, interfaces were not detected and also says assembly reference is missing.

**What I have tried ?**
1. I have tried putting each of the binding libraries in two different C# library projects and then referring the C# wrapper libraries not directly to the android binding libraries but it is still showing up the same error.
2. I have tried to load the binding libraries using reflection during run-time but I cannot do that because I need to implement interface present in .jar file to my c# class.

Can you please help me how do I resolve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: It always helped when at least the error message was provided. Naming the libs you have bindings for does also help to find a solution.

Comment: It Says assembly reference is missing.

Comment: What assembly reference does it say that you are missing?